# Javascript function with Ajax calling controller function on MVC .net not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, asp.net-mvc

When I press a button I do this function, i save in one array some parameters from a table row when checked, once done that i call ajax to go to my function called **insertarfaltas** in my "controllers" folder, the problem is that i can't reach there.

The only output i'm getting is Uncaught

> SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor
>   'insertarfaltas'.

What's wrong? I just want to pass an ARRAY to my controllers function called **insertarfaltas**.

```
 $('#guardarfaltas').click(function() {
            var i = 0;
            var alumnes = [];
            var fechactual = SaberFechaActual();
            $('#tablaalumnos tr').each(function () {
                var id = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
                var checkbox = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();
                var comentario = $(this).find("#comentario").val();

                if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
                    alumnes[i] = [id,comentario,fechactual,hora,codiuf,codicurs,codimodul];
                    i++;
                }
            });

            alumnes = JSON.stringify(alumnes);
            console.log(alumnes);


            $.ajax({
                url: @Url.Action("insertarfaltas","Faltas"),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: {alumnes : alumnes},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

---- Controllers folder:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public String insertarfaltas(String[] alumnes)
        {

            String[] a = alumnes;
            return ("hola ionah");


        }
```

Comment: By the looks of it, variable `alumnes` isn't an array of string, it's `array[array[string]]`

Comment: Yes because there might be more than 1 so i need 2 [0]['whatever']['whatever2'][1]['whatever]['whatever']. My problem is trying to reach the other page, i can fix all little problems later i guess but first i want to reach there with a simple array, any example?

Comment: Does it have to be a string array, or would binding to an object be better cause it's more descriptive?

Comment: I don't care how to do it bu i need like 6 parameters for row in a bidimensional array and pass it trhough ajax or whatever to the other page and get that array, maybe an example with a simple array with this code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure precisely what the problem is because I'm not sure that you have posted the relevant code, but as I said in the comments I have identified that your array isn't of type `String[]` it is more like `array[array[string]]` like a multidimensional array or something,

However, I would be tempted to change your binding to an object as this is more descriptive within your code.

**Action**

```
public ActionResult AnotherAction(List<MyRequestModel> model)
{

}
```

**Binding Model**

```
public class MyRequestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Commentario { get; set; }
    public string Fechactual { get; set; }
    public string Hora { get; set; }
    public string Codiuf { get; set; }
    public string Codicurs { get; set; }
    public string Codimodul { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your JavaScript declaration to something along the lines of:

```
alumnes[i] = { 
               Id: id,
               Comentario: comentario
               Fechactual: fechactual,
               Hora: hora,
               Codiuf: codiuf,
               Codicurs: codicurs,
               Codimodul: codimodul
};
```

Comment: what i actually need is a multidimensional array, saving in 00,01,02,03, then another person would be 10,11,12,12, another person, 20,21,22,23, so i need a multidimensional array passing to my function, i can't go with a simple array because that would make me do some foreach array i get and would make the page go really slow

Answer (score 0):

Try calling JSON.stringify like this:

```
var sData = JSON.stringify({model: alumnes});

$.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("insertarfaltas","Faltas")',
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     traditional: true,
     data: sData,
     success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
     }
});
```

I would try converting the two dimensional array to a ViewModel as @Coulton has suggested.

Then use the JSON.stringify method I have suggested.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnotherAction(List<MyRequestModel> model)
{

}
```

@Coulton is Saying to change your jQuery to Something like this:

```
$('#guardarfaltas').click(function() {
            var i = 0;
            var alumnes = [];
            var fechactual = SaberFechaActual();
            $('#tablaalumnos tr').each(function () {
                var id = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
                var checkbox = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();
                var comentario = $(this).find("#comentario").val();

if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
               alumnes[i] = { 
               Id: id,
               Comentario: comentario
               Fechactual: fechactual,
               Hora: hora,
               Codiuf: codiuf,
               Codicurs: codicurs,
               Codimodul: codimodul
               };
                    i++;
                }
            });

            var sData = JSON.stringify({model: alumnes});
            console.log(sData);


            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("insertarfaltas","Faltas")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: sData,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
});
```

AND Also create the `ViewModel` @Coulton suggested: `MyRequestModel`

**EDIT**
try taking you URL out the JavaScript:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("insertarfaltas","Faltas")'

       $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: sData,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
```

});

Comment: I'm new to MVC like for some few days, i've done yours but i don't know how to do what Coulton has done there.
Still have same problem: SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'insertarfaltas'.

Comment: Can you see the line that the exception happens on when debugging?

Comment: {"alumnes":[["6285","","04-16-2015",3,2857,13,1277],["6298","","04-16-2015",3,2857,13,1277]]}
Faltas:273 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'Faltas'.<-- That's all i have from debugging.

Comment: What i did finally is making a simple action, putting in a string with " " to separate each word and then in the action split them into an array. Thanks all for helping.

Comment: That will definitely slow your application down